# Tomcat 8 NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryUtils

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Got error:

> NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryUtils

when deploying project on Tomcat 8. But in Tomcat 7 it's deployed and run without any problems.

```
<spring.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<springSecurity.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</springSecurity.version>

Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
JVM Version 1.8.0_31-b13
```

In the web I found only one solution: reinstall Tomcat or change version, but it runs on the remote client server. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have [spring-orm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19686937/2071828) in your dependencies?

Comment: Yes spring-orm included, I think without it will also failed in Tomcat 7

Comment: Not if, for whatever reason, it was in Tomcat's `lib` folder on the other server.

Comment: Boris answer correctly, adding spring-orm to Tomcat lib solve the problem. Thx a lot!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that - it's a really rather bad idea.

Comment: I meant put it in project web-inf/lib or what is best practice?

Comment: `WEB-INF/lib` is good. `CATALINA_HOME/lib` is bad.